# Realloc pointer that is malloced in different function

Tags: c, pointers, memory, malloc, realloc

I have this function:

```
static void unfoldLines(char **pbuff, char **lines, int foldCount) {
    int i, j;

    for(i = 1; i <= foldCount; i++) {
        removeEOL(lines[i]);
        for(j = 0; j < strlen(lines[i]); j++) {
            while(isspace(lines[i][j])) {
                lines[i]++;
            }
        }
    }

    lines[1] = realloc(lines[1], sizeof(char) * (strlen(lines[1]) +
                strlen(lines[2]) + 1));
    exit(0);
}
```

`lines` and it's pointers has been malloced in a previous function. When I try to realloc lines[1], I get this error:

`malloc: *** error for object 0x7fcec0404fe1: pointer being realloc'd was not allocated`

I know it has been malloced, so why can't it be realloced in this function?

Comment: Because it increments the pointer.

Comment: Crap! Should I a) not increment the pointer or b) is there a way around this?

Comment: It moves each character.

Comment: I understand that incrementing the pointer changes the address, making me able to realloc/free it. I increment the pointer to remove any leading whitespace. What should I do here?

Comment: remove the spaces by moving all char

Comment: @Ôrel By shifting all characters left however many spaces there are at the beginning?

Comment: yeap, with two pointer it is quite easy,

Comment: @Ôrel With two pointers? How?

Comment: @MortalMan [remove leading whitespaces](http://ideone.com/nzvU5l)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lines[1]` gets incremented in the for-loop. You should keep the original pointer(s) that are returned from `malloc()` and use those with `realloc()`.

Also, `realloc()` can fail, so you should store the return value of `realloc()` in a temporary pointer, and only on success transfer that to the original pointer.